# Pandas: Read dates in column which has different formats

Tags: pandas, datetime

I would like to read a csv, with dates in a column, but the dates are in different formats within the column.

Specifically, some dates are in "dd/mm/yyyy" format, and some are in "4####" format (excel 1900 date system, serial number represents days elapsed since 1900/1/1).

Is there any way to use `read_csv` or `pandas.to_datetime` to convert the column to datetime?

Have tried using `pandas.to_datetime` with no parameters to no avail.

`df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])`

Returns

`ValueError: year 42613 is out of range`

Presumably it can read the "dd/mm/yyyy" format fine but produces an error for the "4####" format.

Note: the column is mixed type as well

Appreciate any help

Example

```
dates = ['25/07/2016', '42315'] 
df = DataFrame (dates, columns=['Date'])
#desired output ['25/07/2016', '07/11/2015']
```

Comment: Can you include a sample frame as a copyable piece of code, and expected output to test solutions against?

Comment: Thanks, added example input/output

Comment: What is the dateformat of `42315` what does the `423` represent? I assume `15` is the 2 digit year.

Comment: Hi Henry, that date format is the date representation for 2015-11-07 under the excel 1900 date system, the serial number represents days elapsed since 1900/1/1.
I.e. if you enter 42315 as a number into excel and change the format to a date, it will return 2015-11-07.

Comment: @jeremyw, can you split of the dataset in two different dataframes: one type of dates in each dataframe? E.g. convert the column with dates to string and select those, which have '/' symbol, and which not. After this step, you can process these dates in different way or unify their formats.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try:

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True, errors='coerce')
m = dates.isna()
dates.loc[m] = (
        pd.TimedeltaIndex(df.loc[m, 'Date'].astype(int), unit='d')
        + pd.Timestamp(year=1899, month=12, day=30)
)
df['Date'] = dates
```

Or alternatively with seconds conversion:

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True, errors='coerce')
m = dates.isna()
dates.loc[m] = pd.to_datetime(
    (df.loc[m, 'Date'].astype(int) - 25569) * 86400.0,
    unit='s'
)
df['Date'] = dates
```

`df`:

```
        Date
0 2016-07-25
1 2015-11-07
```

---

Explanation:

1. First convert to datetime all that can be done with [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas-to-datetime):

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True, errors='coerce')
```

2. Check which values couldn't be converted:

```
m = dates.isna()
```

3. Convert `NaT`s

a. Offset as days since `1899-12-30` using [`TimedeltaIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.TimedeltaIndex.html) + [`pd.Timestamp`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html):

```
dates.loc[m] = (
        pd.TimedeltaIndex(df.loc[m, 'Date'].astype(int), unit='d')
        + pd.Timestamp(year=1899, month=12, day=30)
)
```

b. Or convert serial days to seconds mathematically:

```
dates.loc[m] = pd.to_datetime(
    (df.loc[m, 'Date'].astype(int) - 25569) * 86400.0,
    unit='s'
)
```

4. Update the `Date` column:

```
df['Date'] = dates
```